# Display Responsive Banner Image with Link from Another Website?

Tags: image, web, hyperlink, responsive, banner

Is there a way to Display a "Responsive" Image with hyperlink from another Website?

Bonus: If there's also a way to have a lightweight view and click counter back to source website?

Basically like a super light weight fast loading banner with link and basic tracking statistics.

I tried search this topic online but didn't find how to do it.

RE:

What type of click counter are you interested in? Something that shows the count of clicks to all your visitors? Something that records the clicks so that you can see them? Something that records the clicks so that the site you are linking to sees them? Are you or this other site using Google Analytics? – Stephen Ostermiller Apr 28 at 6:57

> Wanting a counter to see clicks vs Views for a view to click ratio to see which banner ads are more effective than others.

RE:

I don't know what you mean by "lightweight view" What makes a view "lightweight" on the web? That isn't a standard term that I'm familiar with. – Stephen Ostermiller

> My websites are build with Joomla 4 using a banner ad extension called SocialAds - [https://techjoomla.com/social-ads](https://stackoverflow.com) but this is bulky slow loading using IFrames which are not responsive image banners. So, I want something simple fast loading but centralized from 1 website to add banners to dozens of websites.

RE:

Links like can't be used to display images, only show them when the link is clicked. Are you sure you want to use a hyperlink and not an image tag like ? – Stephen Ostermiller Apr 28 at 6:54

> Whichever way that can load an image with a hyperlink as fast as possible from website to another for SEO purposes.

I posted this question on StackOverFlow but it was closed in 1 day and I didn't have time to respond.

I found this website https://owlcation.com/stem/JavaScript-Banner-Rotator with the follow website & script the works for the basic Image with Link which shows a random image when you refresh the page.

```js
var banner = [
["destination1.com", "placeholder.com/image1.jpg"],
["destination2.com", "placeholder.com/image2.jpg"],
["destination3.com", "placeholder.com/image3.jpg"],
["destination4.com", "placeholder.com/image4.jpg"]
];

function shuffle(a) {
    var j, x, i;
    for (i = a.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
        x = a[i];
        a[i] = a[j];
        a[j] = x;
    }
    return a;
}

shuffle(banner);

document.getElementById('ad-container').innerHTML = '<a href="'+banner[0][0]+'" target="_blank" rel="nofollow"><img src="'+banner[0][1]+'" height="250" width="300" alt="300x250 Banner Ad" /></a>';
```

*Responsive Design*

If your website is responsive, perhaps the banner's container will be hidden on narrow-enough screens. If that's the case, you should prevent the banner from loading to make your website faster for mobile users. Edit the original rotator script by adding the following check:

```js
if (window.matchMedia("(min-width: 1024px)").matches) {
    //the original script goes here
}
```

*The HTML*

You should have an empty container div with the ID of ad-container somewhere in your HTML, into which the script will dynamically insert the banner:

```html
<div id="ad-container"></div>
```

*Loading the Script*

Now load the script by putting the following anywhere between your  tags:

```html
<script src="/rotator.js" async></script>
```

#1. How can I make the images switch/rotate automatically without needing to refresh the webpage lets say image switch every 3 second?

#2. Is there a way to setup a simple image tracker to count views and clicks?

??? After a few days on multiple website the banners stopped displaying through the iframe but still worked on [https://ebads.net/network-banner-ads.html][1]

[1]: https://ebads.net/network-banner-ads.html ???